# How to catch an event when the horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

Given:

1. page with a horizontal scrolling (jInvertScroll.js),
2. when certain blocks (with a width of%) appear in the scope, hang the class on other blocks.
   Please tell me how to implement a horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem for a scrolling library like ScrollMagic.

Here's there demo for a problem like this: [ScrollMagic Horizontal Scrolling](https://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/going_horizontal.html)

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling (horizontal and vertical) can be reacted upon in the following manner with JS:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log('scroll event');
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: in case there are several blocks in the container with a view = 90%, how to track the appearance of each separately?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be easier to repulse the page height, which is prescribed in the initialization script jInvertScroll.js

That is, there were several conditions, for example:

```
if ($ (window) .scrollTop ()> 3000 && $ (window) .scrollTop () <4500) {
```

// our action

}

Thanks to all who responded!